# Why can't you add a Vue.js reactive property directly to root model?

Tags: vue.js

Here is some code that uses `$set()` to add a new reactive prop to the model. It works fine.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            Prop1: {{ x.prop1 }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Go" @click="go()">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',

        data() {
            return {
                x: {}
            };
        },

        methods: {
            go() {
                this.$set(this.x, 'prop1', 'yay');
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Now, if I remove the `x` root property and try to add `prop1` directly to the `this` it doesn't work.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            Prop1: {{ prop1 }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Go" @click="go()">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',

        data() {
            return {
            };
        },

        methods: {
            go() {
                this.$set(this, 'prop1', 'yay');
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I get that you should do this kind of thing, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set):

> The target object cannot be a Vue instance, or the root data object of a Vue instance.

It's a technical limitation.